# Shell: How to calculate current MMYY to previous date (-15 months)

Tags: shell

I am trying to calculate the current date MMYY - 15 months ago.

I get current date in the format I want with shell command: date +"%m%y"

I am trying to use this current date and calculate what the MMYY is 15 months ago, what command would show me this?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you want to get the current `MMYY` and calculate "15 months ago" afterwards. You could just do it in one command:

```sh
date --date='15 months ago' +"%m%y"
```

`man date` and `info date` are your friend.